# Can't add a new Cassandra datacenter due to streaming errors

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

Using DSE 4.8.6 (C* 2.1.13.1218)

When I try adding a new node in a new datacenter, bootstraping / node rebuild is always interrupted by streaming errors.

Error example from system.log:

```
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/172.31.47.213] 2016-04-19 12:30:28,531  StreamSession.java:621 - [Stream #743d44e0-060e-11e6-985c-c1820b05e9ae] Remote peer 172.31.47.213 failed stream session.
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/172.31.47.213] 2016-04-19 12:30:30,665  StreamResultFuture.java:180 - [Stream #743d44e0-060e-11e6-985c-c1820b05e9ae] Session with /172.31.47.213 is complete
```

There is about 500GB of data to be streamed to the new node. Boostrap or rebuild operation stream those from 4 different nodes on the other (main) DC.

When a streaming error occurs, all synced data is wiped (and I have to start over).

What I tried so far:

- bootstraping the node
- setup `auto_boostrap: False` in `cassandra.yaml` and manually run `nodetool rebuild`
- disabling `streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms` and setting up more aggressive TCP Keep Alive values in my linux conf (following advice in the [CASSANDRA-9440](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9440) ticket)
- increasing `phi_convict_threshold` (to the max)
- do not bootstrap the node and use repair to stream the data (stopping the repair at a nearly full disk and 80K SSTables. After 3 days of trying to compact them, I gave up)

Any other things I should try ? I'm in the process of running `nodetool scrub` on every failing node to see if this helps...

On the stream out node, these are the error messages:

```
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/172.31.45.28] 2016-05-11 13:10:43,842  StreamSession.java:505 - [Stream #ecfe0390-1763-11e6-b6c8-c1820b05e9ae] Streaming error occurred
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:229) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:51) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:257) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.14.1272.jar:2.1.14.1272]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

and then:

```
INFO  [STREAM-IN-/172.31.45.28] 2016-05-10 07:59:14,023  StreamResultFuture.java:180 - [Stream #ea1271b0-1679-11e6-917a-c1820b05e9ae] Session with /172.31.45.28 is complete
WARN  [STREAM-IN-/172.31.45.28] 2016-05-10 07:59:14,023  StreamResultFuture.java:207 - [Stream #ea1271b0-1679-11e6-917a-c1820b05e9ae] Stream failed
ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/172.31.45.28] 2016-05-10 07:59:14,024  StreamSession.java:505 - [Stream #ea1271b0-1679-11e6-917a-c1820b05e9ae] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.AssertionError: Memory was freed
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.checkBounds(SafeMemory.java:97) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.getLong(Memory.java:249) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.getTotalSizeForSections(CompressionMetadata.java:247) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.FileMessageHeader.size(FileMessageHeader.java:112) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.fileSent(StreamSession.java:546) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:50) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:41) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:45) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:358) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:338) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.13.1218.jar:2.1.13.1218]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered in the Cassandra ticket [CASSANDRA-11345](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11345), this issue was due to a big SSTable file (40GB) being transferred.

The transfer of said file takes more than 1 hour and by default streaming operations time out if an outgoing transfer takes more than 1 hour.

To change this default behavior you can set the [streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms) in the `cassandra.yaml` configuration file to a large value (eg: 72000000 ms or 20 hours)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change this value on the existing nodes too, not just the new nodes!
(not that I'm admitting anything here...)